# How to create a jar with tests and run it from another version of project?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-plugin

I have a project with version 1.0 with 3 package (maven projects).

project1 (version 1.0)
--------backward-tests (src/test/java + pom.xml)
--------pack1 (src/main/java + pom.xml)
--------pack2 (src/main/java+ pom.xml)

I want to save backward-tests jar with tests from here for using in version 1.x, where x > 1.
The project with version 1.x will show like the following:

project1 (version 1.1)
--------run-tests (pom.xml)
--------pack1 (src/main/java + pom.xml)
--------pack2 (src/main/java+ pom.xml)

Thr question: How should be the pom.xml files in backward-tests and run-tests packages for let me run the tests?
I have to mention that backward-tests has dependecies of pack1 and pack2.
Thank you.

Edit:
I have tried something like that in run-tests pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <dependenciesToScan>
            <dependency>groupId:artifactId</dependency>
        </dependenciesToScan>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but it doesn't work.

Edit2: the answer of @andolsi zied probably is fine, but on mvn clean install there are no failed tests even if I added a wrong change in the class which I test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In backward-tests add this plugin to pom.xml that maven package the test class in backward-tests-test.jar

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In run-tests add this dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>backward-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.x</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pack1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pack2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I tried, but there is a problem with the dependencies of pack1 and pack2. Because when I run in version 1.2 there is used the dependecy 1.0 of pack1 and pack2 and I don't want that.

Comment: I do not understand your problem, you can put the version you want in dependency test.

Comment: In backward-tests pom.xml I have dependecy of pack1 and pack2 with version 1.0. Then in run-tests pom.xml I have only the dependecy of backward-tests version 1.0. And there is a problem because in run-tests it is used the dependecy of pack1 and pack2 version 1.0 becasuse of backward-tests dependecy version 1.0. Sorry for my english.

Comment: You can exclude them from the dependency

Comment: Thank you. I will try. And for run that tests should I execute command: mvn clean install?and that's all? or mvn test? because the tests are not runned with mvn clean install.

Comment: `install` is a cycle pahse in maven build that includes `test` phase, so if tests are not runned, you are probably missing some thing in your java test class.

Answer (score 0):

another way of running the tests against differen project versions is using git (or any other SCM).

- create a git repository in your project V1
- check in test sources only
- create a git-branch `project-v1` and check that out.
- checkin the project production code V1
- create a git-branch `project-v2` and check that out.
- checkin the project production code V2

now you can run the test on the version checked out (either V1 or V2). Additionally you see for failed code what the exact difference is by looking at the SCM's history.